# cakephp creating new table when add new category from Form, Need own table for this category

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

all please, 
**Running custom query on cakephp Controller** 
when i add new category, I want to add new table within controller with category name.I did not found anything on google cakephp query to add new table..

I'd appreciate your help. I'm not too familiar with CakePHP, so please go easy on me

//CategoriesController.php

```
function admin_add_category($tbl = null){
//saving category code..
$tbl = $this->request->data['category']['cat_name'];
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tbl (id int primary key)";
$this->Category->execute($sql);

}
```

Comment: First thing $this->request not $this->requst... Second CakePHP book should be your best friend not Google

Comment: SQL injections here we come... _never ever_ inject user data into queries without properly escaping/sanitizing it! Also a separate table per category? Really?

Comment: i use 2.3.8 version, i can't tags this version. @AD7six

Comment: 2.3 is the appropriate tag. Tagging as both 2.0 and 2.3 is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP does not work like this.

Using `$this->Category->execute($sql);` means to use the Model of `Category` which calls a specific table.

Even though you can create the new table you cannot access the table easily, because one table is bound on a single Model and a single Controller.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question - he's not trying to access the newly created table in the question. And this is simply not true: "one table is bound on a single Model **and a single Controller**".

Comment: I am sry. English is not my mother tongue. What I wanted to say is the following:
CakePHP does not automatically add a database table to a model or can be accessed automatically. He need to use more SQL queries to access the new tables and cakePHP can't help him with the security and other advantages of a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from my friend's help.
Any query can run in CakePHP on this Model Call.

```
function admin_add_category($tbl = null){
//saving category code..
    $tbl = $this->request->data['category']['cat_name'];
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tbl (id int primary key)";
    $this->Category->query($sql);
    //Any other Query can run on $sql With this Model 
}
```

Comment: You should never put sql in a controller, it should always be in a model method. You should **definitely** guard against sql injection because whether you think the above is protected because it's an admin action or not, that's an invite to abuse waiting to happen.